# Como os números devem ser localizados?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, localização

Reparei na [tela de privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) que os números nesse site estão formatados conforme o padrão inglês/americano: vírgula usada como separador de milhar:

> 4,000 usuário confiável
>
> 3,500 proteger perguntas
>
> ...

Aqui no Brasil usamos a vírgula como separador de decimais, e o ponto como separador de milhar. Não sei como é em Portugal.

Como esses (e talvez outros) números devem ser localizados no SOPT?

Comment: Em Portugal é como no Brazil, aliás penso que a Europa usa ponto também.

Comment: @Sergio A Europa **toda** acho que não, me lembro de ter visto umas variações bem estranhas de país pra país... Mas como é igual no Brasil e em Portugal (os dois maiores públicos do site) então creio que a localização dos números deveria seguir esse padrão.

Comment: Concordo, sim de facto não sei se é a Europa toda. Mas em PT é como o Brazil. Aqui na Suécia é também o ponto.

Answer (score 2):

Esta [fonte discutivelmente confiável](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal#Pa.C3.ADses_que_utilizam_numerais_ar.C3.A1bicos_com_v.C3.ADrgula_decimal) mostra em que países se utiliza o ponto como separador de milhar e a vírgula como separador decimal. Acredito que todos os países de língua portuguesa utilizam a vírgula como separador decimal.

Agora, sinceramente... Se der para entender como está escrito, para mim tanto faz se utilizam o ponto, a vírgula, a forma medieval ou qualquer que seja. Sou programador até à alma. Minha mente sempre traduz qualquer forma numérica para uma representação sem separador de milhar e com o ponto como separador decimal ;)

Comment: Minha mente sempre traduz qualquer forma númerica com uma vírgula no meio como dois números distintos. Quantos parâmetros tem aqui? `func(2,546)` :D

Comment: Renan, então sou a favor de haver uma exceção no sistema para sempre mostrar sua reputação em algarismos romanos. Ou em binário :D

Comment: @bfavaretto talvez em pontos mesmo. Exemplo: 9 pontos ficariam ::::.

Comment: Eu não acho que o formato dos números seja "*big deal*", lembro de no ensino fundamental já estar ciente de que alguns países usavam a vírgula e outros o ponto para decimal (embora vírgula para milhar demorou um pouco para eu entrar em contato). Mesmo assim, a questão permanece... Entendo que sua opinião é "tanto faz", e é uma opinião válida. :)

Comment: O uso dos separadores no padrão americano foi um problema de internacionalização. Vai ser resolvido com o tempo.

Comment: Acho que devemos usar hexadecimais com o separador `:` a cada 4 caracteres :D. [IPV6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) *style*! Problema de internacionalização resolvido, e ainda por cima fica mais conciso! :D.

Comment: Lá na lista pouco confiável dá pra ver que é aquela turminha que usa o Sistema Imperial, ô pessoal estranho, o planeta inteiro decide por um sistema científico e ele insistem em usar as convenções da idade média... pfsss...